# Deriving Equation of a Plane

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose that in the following graphic, the orange parallelogram represents a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which does **not** pass through the origin, whilst $P_1$ and $P_2$ represent *points* which lie on the plane. Is it possible to derive the equation of the plane with no more information than that given here (i.e. the two known points - $P_1$ and $P_2$)?

[image]

Comment: two points determine a line, and there are infinitely many planes containing that line

Comment: If you know the parallelogram, then you know the plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two points determine a line, and there are infinitely many planes containing that line, so it is not possible to specify the equation of **the** plane containing them, without further information.  If, however, we are given a particular normal vector to the plane, then it is possible.  Note that the normal vector must be perpendicular to $P_2-P_1$.  For example, if $P_1=(1,0,0)$ and $P_2=(0,1,0)$, then $P_2-P_1=(-1,1,0)$, so the normal vector must be in the direction $(1,1,k),$ for some $k,$ in order to be perpendicular to (i.e., have zero dot product with) $(-1,1,0)$.  The equation of the plane will then be $1x+1y+kz=D$.  In order to find $D$, note that plugging in either $P_1$ or $P_2$ (both of which must lie in the plane) shows $D=1$.  So the equation of a plane containing $P_1$ and $P_2$ is $x+y+kz=1$, where $k$ is arbitrary.  (Note that the stipulation that the plane does not contain the origin excludes the plane $0x+0y+kz=0$.)

Comment: when you say "so the normal vector is of the form $(n_1,n_1,n_3)$" - did you mean to say $(n_1,n_2,n_3)$? Or did you duplicate the $n_1$ component deliberately? If so, why?

Comment: Also why is $D = n_1$?

Comment: I deliberately wrote $n_1$ in the second component to show the form of a vector normal to $(-1,1,0)$, and $D=n_1$ because $P_1$ and $P_2$ are in the plane

Comment: Sorry, maybe I am being stupid here, but I really don't understand the significance of "the form of $(n_1,n_1,n_3)$". What are you trying to represent with '$n_1$' and '$n_3$'? Could you elaborate on this more in your answer perhaps?

Comment: Ok, @RyanWalter, I edited my answer

Comment: Okay, now I see where you are getting $(1,1,k)$ from. Unfortunately I'm still not totally on the same page as you. Can you explain what you mean by "plugging in either $P_1$ or $P_2$ shows $D=1$"? Can you show me how and why you would 'plug' these in?

Comment: I mean that, for example, since $(0,1,0)$ is on the plane and the plane equation is $1x+1y+kz=D$, then $1\times0+1\times1+k\times0=1=D$

Comment: Ah yes, fantastic. I see what you mean now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97879/discussion-between-ryan-walter-and-j-w-tanner).

Answer (score 1):

No. Two points are not enough ! Example: the planes

$x+y+z=1$

and

$2x+2y=2$

both contain the points $P_1=(1,0,0)$ and $P_2=(0,1,0).$

Comment: Would it be possible if we also had the normal vector?

Comment: If we had the normal vector, then we could determine the equation of the plane

Comment: @J. W. Tanner could you show us how this is done with an answer? It's simple enough if the plane goes through the origin, but I can't think how this would work in a situation where we have two known points, a known normal vector, and a plane that does not pass through the origin.